# Library used by Microsoft calculator

Tags: c++, assembly, sse

Never touched Microsoft's Windows 7 calculator program. It was really surprising that calculator program has a accuracy up to 32 decimal places. Microsoft surely does not uses MPIR or other library which treat number as string. does the calculator program  is using intrinsic function?

I would like to write a program to calculate log of a double up to 32 decimal place using these intrinsic function.

Comment: What about something like [this](http://www.nongnu.org/hpalib/)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure their floating point uses 10 byte extended precision floats. That's a natively supported number format on Intel. On the integer side, it's 64 bits, natively supported by the MS C compiler.

Comment: 10 bytes = 80 bits, of which 64 are "mantissa" -> around 20 digits.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev It's capable of representing an epsilon far less than that of a binary80. As far as I can tell, it's a binary128 type, with 112 mantissal bits.

Answer (score 7):

I have absolutely no idea what math library MS uses in the calculator (if it's a "library" as such in the first place, and not just part of the overall calculator code) - nor do I really want to know that - but it's not terribly hard to write the "multiprecision" functions for a calculator. The key part of this phrasing is "for a calculator", because the math doesn't really have to be particularly fast. As long as you can do the four basic math operations (`+`, `-`, `*` and `/`), the rest can be produces using various series calculations. For 30 digits precision, you probably need a few more loops than for the 8-16 digits you get for regular `float` or `double` types, but since we're talking "calculator", it doesn't really matter, as long as the result comes back within a few tenths of a second, it's fine. A modern desktop processor will do many millions of instructions in a second.

I'm 99% sure there is no intrinsics involved, as there is no direct hardware support for "large math", and intrinsic functions are typically implementing hardware functionality (such as SSE, AVX, etc).

The wikipedia page for [Taylor Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) shows the series for `log` and `sin`, and the [Mathematical Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_series) page has a more longer list of different series calculations. Typically, these series calculations can be done with an add, a divide and a multiply per loop iteration, if you keep track of your factors and divisors through the loop.

Edit: It's quite likely that the calculator, when possible, uses the [`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) type that is part of the C# language.

Comment: Vote up require 15 reputation,sorry.

Comment: Taylor series have no relevance to the uniform approximation required to implement `log` or `sin` efficiently. http://lolengine.net/blog/2011/12/21/better-function-approximations